# Next JS Router - routing [...slug] not rendering properly

Tags: javascript, reactjs, next.js, storyblok

I have a top level page for that I use for 95% of the content at `/[...slug].js` I have a headless CMS so I don't need to create individual folders for routes.

I have content within folder structures in the CMS such as `/holidays/railways` and `/holidays/cruising` and on the front end I can access it as is, all good.

However, when putting Next JS Link and Router in these pages and upon clicking them, the URL will eventually update but the content will stay the same.

I've tried doing:

```
<NextLink href="/[...slug]" as="/holidays/cruising">
  Destinations test
</NextLink>
```

and the url is now `/holidays/cruising` but the content is still `/holidays/railways` - has anyone come across this issue before?

I have been tempted to create the `holidays` folder in Next JS pages and put a `[slug].js` but don't want to try this if this won't work.

Here is my `/[...slug].js` page

```
import Head from "next/head";
import Storyblok, { useStoryblok } from "lib/storyblok";
import Components from "components";
import ThemeProvider from "ThemeProvider";

const Slug = ({ page, preview }) => {
  let story = useStoryblok(page, preview);

  return (
    <ThemeProvider>
      <Head>
        <title>Page</title>
      </Head>
      <Components {...story.content} key={story.content._uid} />
    </ThemeProvider>
  );
};

export default Slug;

export async function getStaticProps({ params = {}, preview }) {
  let slug = params.slug ? params.slug.join("/") : "home";
  let sbParams = {
    version: "published",
    cv: "",
    resolve_relations: ""
  };

  if (preview) {
    sbParams.version = "draft";
    sbParams.cv = Date.now();
  }

  const { data } = await Storyblok.get(`cdn/stories/${slug}`, sbParams);

  let props = {
    page: data.story || {},
    preview: preview || false
  };

  return {
    props,
    revalidate: 60
  };
}

export async function getStaticPaths() {
  let { data } = await Storyblok.get("cdn/links/");
  let paths = [];

  Object.keys(data.links).forEach(link => {
    if (data.links[link].is_folder || data.links[link].slug === "home") return;
    paths.push({ params: { slug: data.links[link].slug.split("/") } });
  });

  return {
    paths,
    fallback: "blocking"
  };
}
```

storyblok.js

```
import { useEffect, useState } from "react";
import StoryblokClient from "storyblok-js-client";

const Storyblok = new StoryblokClient({
  accessToken: process.env.STORYBLOK_API_KEY,
  cache: {
    clear: "auto",
    type: "memory"
  }
});

export function useStoryblok(originalStory, preview) {
  let [story, setStory] = useState(originalStory);

  // adds the events for updating the visual editor
  // see https://www.storyblok.com/docs/guide/essentials/visual-editor#initializing-the-storyblok-js-bridge
  function initEventListeners() {
    const { StoryblokBridge } = window;
    if (typeof StoryblokBridge !== "undefined") {
      // initialize the bridge with your token
      const storyblokInstance = new StoryblokBridge();

      // reload on Next.js page on save or publish event in the Visual Editor
      storyblokInstance.on(["change", "published"], () =>
        location.reload(true)
      );

      // live update the story on input events
      storyblokInstance.on("input", event => {
        if (story && event.story.content._uid === story.content._uid) {
          setStory(event.story);
        }
      });

      storyblokInstance.on("enterEditmode", event => {
        // loading the draft version on initial enter of editor
        Storyblok.get(`cdn/stories/${event.storyId}`, {
          version: "draft"
        })
          .then(({ data }) => {
            if (data.story) {
              setStory(data.story);
            }
          })
          .catch(error => {
            console.log(error);
          });
      });
    }
  }
  // appends the bridge script tag to our document
  // see https://www.storyblok.com/docs/guide/essentials/visual-editor#installing-the-storyblok-js-bridge
  function addBridge(callback) {
    // check if the script is already present
    const existingScript = document.getElementById("storyblokBridge");
    if (!existingScript) {
      const script = document.createElement("script");
      script.src = "//app.storyblok.com/f/storyblok-v2-latest.js";
      script.id = "storyblokBridge";
      document.body.appendChild(script);
      script.onload = () => {
        // once the scrip is loaded, init the event listeners
        callback();
      };
    } else {
      callback();
    }
  }

  useEffect(() => {
    // only load inside preview mode
    if (preview) {
      // first load the bridge, then initialize the event listeners
      addBridge(initEventListeners);
    }
  }, [initEventListeners, preview]);

  return story;
}

export default Storyblok;
```

Thanks in advance

Comment: If you change your link to `<NextLink href="/holidays/cruising">`, does that make a difference?

Comment: Unfortunately not - I am pushing to my vercel server to see if it's a local server issue

Comment: Does the `story` returned by `useStoryblok` hook change (to the new page's data) upon client-side navigation to another page?

Comment: Hmm no it doesn't, returns the same data as original page but url changes

Comment: Issue's probably there. Can you share the code for the `useStoryblok` hook?

Comment: I've added it - it's default code from their blog post about setting Next JS with their headless CMS (here https://www.storyblok.com/tp/add-a-headless-cms-to-next-js-in-5-minutes)

Comment: I may have potentially fixed it but still testing it but essentially I have updated `[...slug].js` with the following: `let story = page; if (preview) { story = useStoryblok(page, preview); }`so I don't pass the story if I am not in preview mode and therefore passing the updated data forward, fingers crossed

Comment: React will complain about rendering the hook conditionally. You may have to move the check inside the `useStoryblok` hook itself.

Comment: @juliomalves yep you're right - it appears to be working as it should and I can still enter preview mode with no issues too. Thank you very much for your help, it was good to be able to get another pair of eyes on it